# How can I "predict" the outcome of a query?

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my first question on here, but after some excessive searching I could not find a answer on my question and thought maybe you nice folks can help me out :) I am writing a script that behaves differently depending on what products someone had in their order. For explaining purposes: I have 10 customers. They all have a order_id. Within that order_id in a other table are all products_id's stored.

I want toe "predict" if an order has product_id 1 AND product_id 2, cause I need the script to behave differently. All others combinations are fine (so only product 1, or only product 2 or everything >= product 3.

Here is what I got so far (for readabillity, i left non-important stuff out),

```
<?php

$qGetMailadressen = 'A select EMAIL query';

while($emailrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mailadressenresult)) {

$customers_email = $emailrow['emailadres'];

$qGetLaatsteOrderid = 'A select LAST order from this email QUERY';

$orderidrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($GetLaatsteOrderidresult);

$orderid = $orderidrow['orders_id'];
$lecountry = $orderidrow['customers_country'];
$country = $orderidrow['order_language'];

$qGetLaatsteProducten = "A select ALL PRODUCTS from this ORDERID QUERY";

while($productenrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($GetLaatsteProductenresult)){

    $productnaam = $productenrow['products_name'];
    $productquantity = $productenrow['products_quantity'];
    $productid = $productenrow['products_id'];

    }

}
```

So in this last WHILE loop you see I get the product ID I need. And Ideally what I want is:

```
if ($productid == '1' AND $productid == '2'){
//do this
}else{
// do that
}
```

However im aware that is not possible cause its only IN the while loop that I know it. I tried putting all the data in an Array, but since I am out of the while loop im not sure how to do this.

I understand it might be very unclear, and im sorry for this. I hope you guys can help me out so I can clearify myself better if something is not clear.

Thank you!

/love Grumpy

Comment: Try to create an array of product ids and use in_array() function to check the id exist or not.
like $productid[] = $productenrow['products_id'];
if (in_array("1", $productid) AND in_array("2", $productid)){
//do this
}else{
// do that
}

Comment: I'd think you could do this all in one query with `join`s and a `case`. If user has 1 and 3 how should script behave?

Comment: Oke, what if I assume that someone has products_id 1 and 2. If it results in 0 rows, I know its not this combination so i can execute the other part of the script right?

How would I populate this query? Something like this?

Select * from orders_products where order_id = '232393939' and products_id IN (1,2)

However that would return a row if it contains one of them both, so what if i want to ONLY return rows if it contains both?